# When was the most recent update for IE8 released?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to find out when the last update for IE8 happened. On the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)  page for it, it says

> On May 27, 2010, Microsoft released Internet Explorer 8 optimized for Bing and MSN

Is that the last update that IE8 got, or has there been a more recent one? I rather optimistically trying a seach for **IE8 Changelog** but it didn't bring me anything useful back other than the wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Windows Update Catalog](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=internet%20explorer%208), the most recent IE8 update was:

```
Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows Server 2008 (KB3093983) 
10/12/2015
10.8 MB
```

Comment: This particular cumulative update applied to all versions of [IE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3093983) it looks like it isn't limited to just Windows Server 2008.  [Additional Information](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-106?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Ramhound You are correct, but no specific OS was supplied by OP, so I just picked the top one when sorted by date. :) My main goal was to point out the WU Catalog to the OP so they can utilize it themselves. ;)

Comment: Understood.  I find it difficult not to presents all the facts at times.  Curiosity of what the update was, turned into a itch, to provide clarification.